# best praticle to use the client from an google api

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform

i'm using the google API, to be specific, the textToSpeech API.
i made a function to do this conversion, in an separate archive.
And this API require that i create an client.

```
import * as textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech'
const clientGoogle = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
```

but now is my question: is better that i create this client outside the function or inside?

like this:

```
import * as textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech'

const clientGoogle = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
const createAudio = async ()=>{
    const [response] = await clientGoogle.synthesizeSpeech(request);
}
```

or

```
import * as textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech'
    
const createAudio = async ()=>{
     const clientGoogle = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
     const [response] = await clientGoogle.synthesizeSpeech(request);
}
```

what of this usage is better for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should create the client once in the global space. Then access the client member functions as required. Translation, use your first example.

However, I recommend referencing the package like this:

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
```